# Comparing and coloring 2 cells in the same row pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare 2 cells in pandas. To do this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
df = web.DataReader('fb', 'yahoo')
```

With this lambda function to get the dates where `df['Open'] > df['Close']`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['Close'] if x['Close'] <=
                     x['Open'] else np.nan, axis=1)
```

I want to highlight `df['Close']` cell with red once this condition is met:

```
df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color : red' if x['Close'] <=
                     x['Open'] else 'background-color : green')
```

But this is giving me this error:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Could you please advise why is it giving this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should achieve it through this, without applying the first lambda function:

```
def row_style(row):
    if if x['Close'] <= x['Open']:
        return pd.Series('background-color: red', row.index)
    else:
        return pd.Series('background-color: green', row.index)


df.style.apply(row_style, axis=1, subset=['Close'])
```